# Error: 'No database selected'

Tags: php, sql

My first big project is a social media. I was testing my registration system using MAMP. Upon clicking submit, it returned:

> No database selected

Which I assume is talking about the SQL database. My page looks like:

```
<?php require('includes/config.php');

//if logged in redirect to members page
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: memberpage.php'); }

//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//very basic validation
if(strlen($_POST['username']) < 3){
    $error[] = 'Username is too short.';
} else {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :username');
    $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($row['username'])){
        $error[] = 'Username provided is already in use.';
    }
}

if(strlen($_POST['password']) < 3){
    $error[] = 'Password is too short.';
}

if(strlen($_POST['passwordConfirm']) < 3){
    $error[] = 'Confirm password is too short.';
}

if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['passwordConfirm']){
    $error[] = 'Passwords do not match.';
}

//email validation
if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
} else {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = :email');
    $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($row['email'])){
        $error[] = 'Email provided is already in use.';
    }
}

//if no errors have been created carry on
if(!isset($error)){

            $to = 'email';
            $subject = 'Account Verification';
            $message = '
            Thank you for joining the community at Way of Life. You must first verify your identity.

            Please click this link to verify your account: http://www.w-o-l.ml/verify.php?email='.email.'&hash='.$activasion.'  

            Be sure to join a Calling once you log in!
            ';

            mail($to,$subject,$message);

    //hash the password
    $hashedpassword = $user->password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    //create the activasion code
    $activasion = md5( rand(0,1000) );

    try {
        //insert into database with a prepared statement
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (username,password,email,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :active)');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':username' => $_POST['username'],
            ':password' => $hashedpassword,
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':active' => $activasion
        ));
        $id = $db->lastInsertId('memberID');

        //redirect to login page
        header('Location: memberpage.php?action=joined');
        exit;

    //else catch the exception and show the error.
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $error[] = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}
?>

<head>
    <title>Register</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css" >
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo.png">
</head>
<body >
<div class="top">
    <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" style="margin-left:42%; margin-right:auto; height:100%;"></a>
</div>
<div class="main" style="background-image: url(images/background2.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100%; margin:0 -.6% 0 -.6%; padding-bottom:10%;">
<br>
<div class="container" style="margin:5% 33% 0 33%; padding:2.5%; background-color:white;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
            <form role="form" method="post" action="index.php" autocomplete="off">
                <h2>Please Sign Up</h2>
                <hr>
                <?php
                //check for any errors
                if(isset($error)){
                    foreach($error as $error){
                        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$error.'</p>';
                    }
                }
                //if action is joined show success
                if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'joined'){
                    echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Registration successful, please check your email to activate your account.</h2>";
                }
                ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                                        <p>Username</p>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="User Name" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" tabindex="1">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                                        <p>Email</p>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" tabindex="2">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                                <p>Password</p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" tabindex="3">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password" tabindex="4">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <hr>
                <div class="row"  style="margin-bottom:4%;">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="5"></div>
                </div>
                                <a href="index.php">Back to Login</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
     <a href="memberpage.php"><h6 style="display:inline;">My Account</h6></a>
     <a href="help.php"><h6 style="display:inline; margin-left:5%;">Help</h6></a>
     <a href="devs.php"><h6 style="display:inline;">Developers</h6></a>
     <a href="sinfo.php"><h6 style="display:inline;">Site Info</h6></a>
     <a href="translate.php"><h6 style="display:inline;">Translate</h6></a>
<div style="font-size:12px; margin-top:.75%;">
     <?php
     $load = microtime();
     echo 'Page generated in ';
     print ( number_format($load,2));
     echo 's';
     ?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

And the configuration page is:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

//database credentials
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','root');
define('DBNAME','members');

//application address
define('DIR','http://w-o-l.ml/');
define('SITEEMAIL','it@w-o-l.ml');

try {

    //create PDO connection
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';port=8889;dbname='.DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p>'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}

//include the user class, pass in the database connection
include('classes/user.php');
$user = new User($db);

?>
```

The sql database name is 'members'. So where did I miss? What requires the database name?

Comment: Does that error give you a line number or some more information

Comment: no. it truly is a white screen with just that

Comment: How about the error logs?

Comment: login[7122]: USER_PROCESS: 7122 ttys000 and 
 login[7122]: DEAD_PROCESS: 7122 ttys000

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your `config.php` file _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I got -- Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/MAMP/.../index.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/MAMP/.../index.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /Applications/MAMP/.../index.php on line 13

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98514/discussion-between-buildnc-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: Your connecting using PDO. You cannot then try and use `MYSQLi_` functions They are completely seperate extensions and cannot be mixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot connect using a PDO connection and then use a `mysqli_` function call.

If you have used mainly `mysqli_` functions then change your connection to use a `mysqli` connection like this.

```
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','root');
define('DBNAME','members');
$db = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME, 8889);
//$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```